# @Value("#{systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}") not finding AppPropertyDir

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

As the header says, error posted below. I also tried to put the AppPropertyDir in my Environment Variables but that only helped with other injecting issues but not this one!

```
@Configuration("appPropertiesLoader")
public class AppPropertiesLoader {
 // I ommitted other unnecessary code, this is where it fails at injecting
    @Value("#{systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}")
    private String appPropertyDir;
}
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
          metadata-complete="true" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <!-- change below params according to local setup -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>AppPropertyDir</param-name>
        <param-value>C:\Users\properties-location</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

***Error***

```
Caused by: org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1008E: Property or field 'AppPropertyDir' cannot be found on object of type 'java.util.Properties' - maybe not public or not valid?
```

Comment: Use $ instead of # @Value("${systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}")

Comment: Doesn't work:
`Could not resolve placeholder 'systemProperties.AppPropertyDir' in value "${systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}"`

Comment: you are expecting the value to be read as a system property, but set it as a servlet content parameter. These are two different things

Comment: So how do I fix it? I tried putting it as an OS environment Variable but that only partially worked

Comment: you need to create a file called `application.propoerties` in resource folder, then add systemProperties.AppPropertyDir = C:\Users\properties-location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was this! 
`@Value("#{systemProperties.AppPropertyDir}")` has to run on system run (so before everything else)! So there needs to be a `@postConstruct` to run from anywhere within the package of your test class. In your postConstruct method just make sure that you're initializing `AppPropertyDir` to `C:\Users\properties-location`

```
@PostConstruct 
public void init() {
   System.setProperty("AppPropertyDir", "C:\Users\properties-location");
}
```